# parse xlsx data from an stringIO on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I am using aws to fetch some data from s3

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
file = s3.get_object(bucket:'bucket-name', key: file.xlsx)
```

Is there a gem that I can parse the returning data ?

Comment: there are gems for parsing xls like roo, https://github.com/roo-rb/roo

Answer (score 2):

I have used Roo to do that, first I have created a tempfile and written all the StringIO data on it.

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
file_io = s3.get_object(bucket:'bucket-name', key: file.xlsx)
file = Tempfile.new(['temp','.xlsx'])
file.binmode
file.write file_io[:body].read
Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file)
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. This helped me out thank you @Petran